# Is this browser Default behaviour font-size property work without fonts?

Tags: html, css

when i was working on a website few days ago i faced an issue that Spacing between `<ul>` and `<li>` that is  baloon can't be fixed on the border without spacing and here is the code given below

```css
ul {
   width:50%;
   float:left;
   border-bottom:1px solid #666;
}
li {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=62153745" alt="img" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=62153745" alt="img" /></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

After i searched a lot i got the answer i gave `font-size:0;` for `ul`  and it is working,  but i dont know the answer is logically right , because i don't get its logic

here is the working code below just run this snippet too

```css
ul {
   width:50%;
   float:left;
   border-bottom:1px solid #666;
   font-size:0;
}
li {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=62153745" alt="img" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=62153745" alt="img" /></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I know there is a lot of genius developers in this community. am so eager to know this , Please help me to find this logic , All answers must be appreciated

Comment: Yes, that is the standard way to avoid unwanted `white-space` when using `inline-block`.

Comment: how can remove white-space with `font-size` property

Comment: By setting it to 0 on the parent element, re-setting it on the children to what is needed.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Please note that there are browsers which have problems with `font-size:0`; they will use the minimum font size from the user preferences instead. A much better way is to actually remove the space inbetween the li elements. Write `... </li><li> ...`

Comment: @MrLister sorry for saying i dont get this